# Computed property depending on two async computations in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component that at creation fires two requests to a RESTful server. Responses are then stored in the Vue Store appropriately.
This component has a computed property that depends on *both* responses.

But, as designed, any relevant change in the store triggers recomputation of the property and all the consequent updates, for example in the related template.
How would I indicate that the property in fact did not change if only one of the required responses is received and there is no need to do any updates?

Comment: if you can post any code would be beneficial. 
If I understand you correctly - you would like to recalculate the computed only when both of responses change ?

Comment: Use Vuex. All the actions/mutations/getter stuff will in fact result in your problem being resolved. Info: http://vuex.vuejs.org/en/

Comment: Use Promise.all to wait for both promises to resolve before taking action. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: @Potray I do use Vuex, I refered to it as Vue Store. I must clarify: I fire two requests means I instruct Vuex to take two async actions which on completetion, separately and unknowingly of each other (so promises aren't an option), will trigger 2 mutations, which will update the recalculation of the computed property twice. It is the intention to make only one re-computation.

Comment: Then you must use promises, async or something to perform the following flow: Request1 => Request 2 => mutation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post is from quite a while ago but I was running into the same problem. I have not tried this yet but I believe this to be the solution for this problem:

https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html#composing-actions

Especially the last part with the `async/await` example. It makes it clear how you can perform a mutation with multiple async actions.